# How can I load my controllers at application Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-controller

I need to initialize the controller, that I use in another view from my start view.For this purpose I want to call my defined setup() method from that controller.

I can't do that because it is uninitialized until the user goes in that particular view defined by the $stateProvider.

How can I load the controller on the application startup, in order for my setup function from that controller to get initialized?

```
.controller('StartupCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    vm=this;
    var ctrl1=$rootScope.ctrl;
    var config={};

    // DO SOMETHING and create the config
    ctrl1.setup(config);})


.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    vm=this;
    $rootScope.ctrl1=this;
    vm.state="";

    vm.setup(config){
       vm.state=config.state
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't get the use case. A controller should never call an other controller's method. What are trying to do ? I'm pretty sure you should give a look at how to create a Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module has a method run(), which can be used on the initial load of an app. You can define your setup method in there, or you can just set variables o the rootscope:

```
//... initialize myModule before this somewhere
myModule.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.config = {}
    //...
})
```

More information about module methods in the doc (look at run and configuration blocks sections) https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
.controller('StartupCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    vm=this;
    var ctrl1=$rootScope.ctrl;
    var config={};

    // DO SOMETHING and create the config
    ctrl1.setup(config);})


.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope,$rootScope, StartupCtrl) {
    vm=this;
    $rootScope.ctrl1=this;
    vm.state="";

    vm.setup(config){
       vm.state=config.state
    }
});
```

Comment: No, it does not work. I get this Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Ctrl1Provider <- Ctrl1 <- StartupCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=Ctrl1Provider%20%3C-%20Ctrl1%20%3C-%20StartupCtrl
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8895:12
(http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:50449:41) [.....................................]<ion-nav-view name="tab-startup" class="view-container tab-content" nav-view="active" nav-view-transition="ios">

Comment: Nice try, but a controller can't be injected in angular. There is a hackish way to do this, but since it should never be used...